# ¿Al pasar de un activity a otro app se trunca?

Tags: java, android, svg

Buen dia

Tengo app que utiliza imagenes vectoriales .svg, pero al pasar de un activity a otro activity el app se trunca, esto es lo que arroja el logcat:

> 05-07 19:12:24.226 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 SSL3 alert read:W:CN warning close notify
>   05-07 19:12:24.226 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
>   05-07 19:12:24.226 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 SSL3 alert write:W:CN warning close notify
>   05-07 19:12:24.228 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=matgic.000webhostapp.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
>   05-07 19:12:24.228 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
>   05-07 19:12:24.228 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=matgic.000webhostapp.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
>   05-07 19:12:24.228 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
>   05-07 19:12:24.420 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: matgic.000webhostapp.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
>   05-07 19:12:24.422 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/Posix: [Posix_connect Debug]Process matgic.com.matgic :443 
>   05-07 19:12:24.496 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=matgic.000webhostapp.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
>   05-07 19:12:24.496 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
>   05-07 19:12:24.497 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake fd=0x9d0dcfb0 shc=0x9d0dcfb4 timeout_millis=2500 client_mode=1 npn=0x0
>   05-07 19:12:24.497 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
>   05-07 19:12:24.497 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 handshake start in CINIT  before connect initialization
>   05-07 19:12:24.497 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
>   05-07 19:12:24.497 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 info_callback completed
>   05-07 19:12:24.498 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 SSL_connect:error exit in 3RSH_A SSLv3 read server hello A
>   05-07 19:12:24.498 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
>   05-07 19:12:24.498 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=2500
>   05-07 19:12:24.594 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
>   05-07 19:12:24.594 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 SSL_connect:error exit in 3RSC_A SSLv3 read server certificate A
>   05-07 19:12:24.594 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
>   05-07 19:12:24.595 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=2500
>   05-07 19:12:24.606 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
>   05-07 19:12:24.606 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x9d0dcddc arg=0x0
>   05-07 19:12:24.607 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
>   05-07 19:12:24.626 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 cert_verify_callback => 1
>   05-07 19:12:24.644 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 SSL_connect:error exit in UNKWN  SSLv3 read server session ticket A
>   05-07 19:12:24.644 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=-1
>   05-07 19:12:24.644 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 NativeCrypto_SSL_do_handshake ret=-1 errno=11 sslError=2 timeout_millis=2500
>   05-07 19:12:24.720 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake ++
>   05-07 19:12:24.720 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 handshake done in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
>   05-07 19:12:24.720 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 info_callback calling handshakeCompleted
>   05-07 19:12:24.721 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 info_callback completed
>   05-07 19:12:24.721 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 SSL_connect:ok exit in SSLOK  SSL negotiation finished successfully
>   05-07 19:12:24.721 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: doing handshake -- ret=1
>   05-07 19:12:24.721 16668-16989/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 NativeCrypto_SSL_get_certificate => NULL
>   05-07 19:12:25.083 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xb8d0f738
>   05-07 19:12:25.113 16668-16668/matgic.com.matgic D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0xb8b47bb0)
>   05-07 19:12:25.113 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0xb8d0f738 initialize window=0xb8b47bb8, title=matgic.com.matgic/matgic.com.matgic.Digits2
>   05-07 19:12:25.113 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0xb8b47bb0,api=1)
>   05-07 19:12:25.114 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
>   05-07 19:12:25.115 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
>   05-07 19:12:25.154 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 31 upload: x, y, width height = 20, 170, 140, 61
>   05-07 19:12:25.157 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb8bf46f8), client(36), share_fd(55)
>   05-07 19:12:25.157 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8bf46f8) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
>   05-07 19:12:25.168 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb8c0de50), client(36), share_fd(62)
>   05-07 19:12:25.168 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8c0de50) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
>   05-07 19:12:25.193 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb8ba9c78), client(36), share_fd(63)
>   05-07 19:12:25.193 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/GraphicBuffer: register, handle(0xb8ba9c78) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
>   05-07 19:12:25.197 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xb8b329c8,api=1)
>   05-07 19:12:25.199 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8b34590) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
>   05-07 19:12:25.200 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [-]r_hnd(0xb8b34590), client(36), share_fd(61)
>   05-07 19:12:25.200 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8d5f3f0) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
>   05-07 19:12:25.201 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [-]r_hnd(0xb8d5f3f0), client(36), share_fd(57)
>   05-07 19:12:25.202 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8d6f098
>   05-07 19:12:25.202 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/mali_winsys: [MALI] win=0xb8b329d0, native_buffer=0xb8d5e4b0, fd=-1
>   05-07 19:12:25.202 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/GraphicBuffer: unregister, handle(0xb8d6f098) (w:480 h:800 s:480 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
>   05-07 19:12:25.203 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [-]r_hnd(0xb8d6f098), client(36), share_fd(60)
>   05-07 19:12:25.203 16668-16687/matgic.com.matgic D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0xb8b329c8,api=1)
>   05-07 19:17:24.852 16668-16717/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
>   05-07 19:17:24.853 16668-16717/matgic.com.matgic D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0xb8bd0de0 SSL3 alert write:W:CN warning close notify

Este es el código de una de las activity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_digits);

    txtscore=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtscore);
    txtusername=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
    btnyes=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnyes);
    btnno=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnno);
    logout=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.logout);


    //id=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.userid);

    //obtiene las variables de la clase User
    Intent intent =getIntent();
    score=intent.getStringExtra("scoreb");
    username=intent.getStringExtra("usernameb");
    userid=intent.getStringExtra("user_id");

    txtscore.setText(score);
    txtusername.setText(username);
    //id.setText(userid);

    img0=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img0);
    img1=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    img2=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);
    img3=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);
    question=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);

    int color=Integer.parseInt(score);
    if(color<=24)
    {


        txtscore.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    }



    //SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.butterfly);
    //img0.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
    //setContentView(img0);

    //Resources res = getResources();
    //Drawable mariposa = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_butterfly);

    //ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView9);
    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_directions_white_48px);




    //arreglo 1 de tipo entero para setear las imagenes en el mismo

    //animales
    int [] f1={R.drawable.ic_coconut, R.drawable.ic_comet, R.drawable.ic_dolphin, R.drawable.ic_eagle};
    Random r1=new Random();
    int a1=r1.nextInt(4);
    img0.setImageResource(f1[a1]);


    int [] f2={R.drawable.ic_butterfly, R.drawable.ic_bird, R.drawable.ic_cat, R.drawable.ic_germanshepharddog};
    Random r2=new Random();
    int a2=r2.nextInt(4);
    img1.setImageResource(f2[a2]);

    //arreglo 3 (astros)
    int [] f3={R.drawable.ic_apple, R.drawable.ic_appletree, R.drawable.ic_rosered, R.drawable.ic_seal};
    Random r3=new Random();
    int a3=r3.nextInt(4);
    img2.setImageResource(f3[a3]);


    int [] f4={R.drawable.ic_tiger, R.drawable.ic_star, R.drawable.ic_rooster, R.drawable.ic_rainbow};
    Random r4=new Random();
    int a4=r4.nextInt(4);
    img3.setImageResource(f4[a4]);



    //arreglo de cadenas de texto
    int [] f5={R.string.bike, R.string.radio,R.string.shoe, R.string.jersey};
    Random r5=new Random();
    int a5=r5.nextInt(4);
    question.setText(f5[a5]);

    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent logout = new Intent(Digits.this, MainActivity.class);
            Digits.this.startActivity(logout);
        }//fin de método  onclick
    });//fin de register setonclick




    //método para el button btnno
    btnno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            int score2=Integer.parseInt(score);
            score2+=1;
            final int scoreaux=score2;
            final String usernameaux=username;
            final int useraux=Integer.parseInt(userid);


            Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        Log.i("MiTag", "El valor retornado es:" + jsonResponse);
                        if(success)
                        {



                            //Int scoreaux=jsonResponse.getInt("score");
                            //Int useraux=jsonResponse.getInt("user_id");

                            Intent intent=new Intent (Digits.this, Digits2.class);

                            intent.putExtra("id_user", useraux);
                            intent.putExtra("username", usernameaux);
                            intent.putExtra("score", scoreaux);




                            Digits.this.startActivity(intent);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Digits.this);
                            builder.setMessage("User or Id incorrect")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create().show();
                        }
                    }

                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }//fin de método onResponse
            };//fin de Response.Listener<String>

            ScoreRequest scoreRequest= new ScoreRequest(useraux,usernameaux,scoreaux, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(Digits.this);
            queue.add(scoreRequest);

        }//fin de onclick
    });//fin de setOnClickListener

    //fin de método btnno



    btnyes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()//encabezado del objeto onclicklistener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)//encabezado de método
        {
            int score2=Integer.parseInt(score);
            score2-=1;
            final int scoreaux=score2;
            final String usernameaux=username;
            final int useraux=Integer.parseInt(userid);



            Response.Listener<String> responseListener= new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse=new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success= jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        Log.i("MiTag", "El valor retornado es:" + jsonResponse);
                        if(success)
                        {



                            //int scoreaux=jsonResponse.getInt("score");
                            //int useraux=jsonResponse.getInt("user_id");


                            Intent intent=new Intent (Digits.this, Digits2.class);

                            intent.putExtra("id_user", useraux);
                            intent.putExtra("username", usernameaux);
                            intent.putExtra("score", scoreaux);




                            Digits.this.startActivity(intent);


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(Digits.this);
                            builder.setMessage("User or Id incorrect")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create().show();
                        }
                    }

                    catch (JSONException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }//fin de método onResponse
            };//fin de Response.Listener<String>

            ScoreRequest scoreRequest= new ScoreRequest(useraux,usernameaux,scoreaux, responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(Digits.this);
            queue.add(scoreRequest);

        }//fin de onclick
    });//fin de setOnClickListener
    //fin de método del button btn yes


}//fin de oncreate


@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

}

}
```

Comment: Hola Sergio lo que agregas no indica nada, busca donde diga "Caused by", agrega tu código.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo, fijate que el app sigue funcionando, el problema es que en ciertos activitys la transición anterior siguiente no funciona ,ya que regresa a un activity previo

Comment: Trata @Sergio de agregar toda esta información en la pregunta para que sea más entendible, por ejemplo no entendía a que te referías con se "trunca", lo que deseas ahora es que no se conserve la Activity anterior que realizo el Intent, agregué respuesta.

Comment: gracias por tu valiosa ayuda, tienes razón me expliqué mal, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si deseas que no se mantenga la `Activity` anterior usa el método `finish()` después de realizar el `Intent`

```
  ...
  Intent logout = new Intent(Digits.this, MainActivity.class);
  Digits.this.startActivity(logout);
  //finaliza Activity actual.
  finish();
  ...
```

Comment: Agradecido por el apoyo, he colocado finish() en cada Intent pero aún insiste en regresar a una o más actividades anteriores, no se que pueda ser pero seguire intentando, saludos.

Comment: Si realizas finish() después de realizar el intent, no hay forma de que aparezca nuevamnente la misma Activity a menos que realices nuevamente un Intent hacia esa Activity

Comment: cierto, pero por algúna razón esta regresando a actividades anteriores, por ejemplo estoy en la pantalla 1, paso a la pantalla 2, luego en la pantalla 3 cuando intento pasar a la siguiente en lugar de pasara a la pantalla 4 regresa a la 1